# How to solve this vector equation?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, vector

[image]
in what way we continue for this vector equation?

Comment: Please post you Mathematica code. and specify where you found trouble.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong section.

Comment: This is not a *Mathematica* question.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting in matrix form, you can solve for x (and for y and z if desired) as

```
Solve[{{a1, b1, c1}, {a2, b2, c2}, {a3, b3, c3}}.{x, y, z} 
              == {d1, d2, d3}, {x, y, z}]
```